# Need Help profiling indirect function calls with LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to write an LLVM Module pass that profiles the number of occurrences of all unique function caller/callee pairs that occur during runtime in a given program.

There seem to be a ton of examples online of how to do this, but none that are able to account for indirect function calls.

I'm currently working with the most recent version of LLVM 11 so many posts online related to this also have out of date info.

In my setup everything currently works fine except for when there are indirect function calls.

Basic code setup...

```
for (auto &F : M) {
    for (auto &BB : F) {
        for (auto &I : BB) {
            if (auto *CB = dyn_cast<CallBase>(&I)){

                caller_name = F->getName().str();
                Value *callee = CB->getCalledFunction();

                // Indirect Call
                if (callee == nullptr){
                    /* Help needed here! */
                }

                // Direct Call
                else{
                    callee_name = callee.getName().str()
                    /* Update caller/callee pair counter */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some sort of known way to retrieve the callee name of an indirect function call using LLVM? I'm aware that there is a new class in LLVM 11 `AbstractCallSite`, that seems like in might be helpful, but I have not been able to find any examples of how to use it properly.

The closest I've gotten to having a work around is by injecting a call in the IR to print the callee value when an indirect call happens.

```
if (callee == nullptr) {
    IRBuilder<> IndirectBuilder(CB);
    auto *callee_ptr_val = IndirectBuilder.CreatePtrToInt(
          CB->getCalledValue(), Type::getInt64Ty(Ctx));
    IndirectBuilder.CreateCall(print_callee_val,  
          callee_ptr_val);
}
```

When this value is printed during runtime I can look in up in the symbol table of the binary and see what was called, but this is really annoying and it would be great if there were a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than injecting a call to print, you could inject a call to a separate routine that would record this pair in a std::map / hastable / etc.  Then iterate through the contents on program exit.
As for the name of what is invoked, the idea of an indirect function call is that the destination is not known until runtime.

Comment: Recording the exact name isn't generally possible at compile time (if it were, the compiler would have generated a direct function call) but I notice you ask for a name, and you you could find that. For example, if a java method calls x.toString(), the type of x determines which toString() is called, but the name is always toString(). If the name without a class is enough, then you could look at the code leading up to the call, look at the vtable involved, and find the name of the method called, even if you don't find the exact reimplementation.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I think I'm going to go with std::map, and iterate over it along with the symbol table on program exit. I don't need the actual names during execution time, just to be able to figure out what they were afterward. Thanks :)